# Get line number of offending SQL from SqliteException

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I am writing a simple SQL query tool using `System.Data.SQLite`.  When the end user inputs SQL and executes it, I execute `SQLiteCommand.ExecuteReader()`.  When that contains an error, a `SQLiteException` is thrown.  I would like to help the user out by displaying the line number, within their SQL input, that has the error.  Whereas .NET's `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException` class has a collection of `SqlError` objects, each which contain a `LineNumber` property, I don't see anything like that in a `SQLiteException`.  It has a `Data` property but that collection is empty when I inspect it.

I also checked the hierarchy of `SQLiteException`: it does not inherit from `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not provided by SQLite.